# Keeping the video player silent after the recording is completed

Tags: ios, ios8, avfoundation, avplayer, avcapturesession

**How to keep the video player silent after the video recorder has been initialized and the silent switched is turned on?**

In the application I am working on I have a video player (will call it *player*) and a video recorder (will call it *recorder*). If the phone is in silent mode (the switch on the side of the device is turned on to disable the sound) the *player* is kept silent when entering the application which is an expected and desired result. But after the recorder has begun running the session this behavior is lost and the video will play out loud although the silent mode is enabled.

I know specifically where this happens is when `startRunning` is called on an `AVCaptureSession`.
I also know the reason is somewhere in `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` `category` or `mode` property which seem to be changed right after the session begins running.

So what I do at the moment is call

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&error];
```

after the recording is completed to reset the session. The issue is this works in most but not all cases, sometimes reports error, sometimes works with a delay, sometimes doesn't work at all.

**The possible solutions I am looking for are** (any would do)**:**

- Somehow prevent the *recorder* to enable sound playing
- Have a clear way of resetting the category and mode after the recording has completed (no errors or misbehaving)
- Have a clean solution to find the state of the silence button (seems the old functions are deprecated and I found nothing but hacks)
- Any other ideas welcome

An important information is that I have both the *player* and a *recorder* initialized all the time for a quick usage. Also I can control the *player* to be mute.

**What I use for player:**

- `AVFoundation`
- `AVPlayer`
- `AVPlayerLayer`
- The source is an `AVAsset` representing a remote URL

The implementation is pretty standard.

**What I use for the recorder:**

- `AVFoundation`
- `AVCaptureDeviceInput`
- `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`
- `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`
- Again all pretty standard.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Not really. I keep the sound enabled no matter the phone sound button state. The mute is then set on the player itself so you may control the volume only in the application.